# name is not passing through a function to another function in django

Tags: python, django

i am trying to pass a variable called name to pass to a function which is present in another function. I want to pass the variable name to the function plane and check if the values are matching with any of the names in my database.
my views.py is

```
from django.shortcuts import render,redirect
from django.contrib.auth.forms import AuthenticationForm
from .models import Logs,Plane
from .forms import Login
from django.contrib import messages
from django.contrib.auth import authenticate, login ,logout    
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404
from django.http import HttpResponse
import json
from django.http import JsonResponse


# Create your views here.
def loger(request):
    global name
    formy = AuthenticationForm()
    c=[]
    a=Logs.objects.all()
    if request.method == 'POST':
        formy = AuthenticationForm(data=request.POST)
        name=request.POST.get('username')
        password = request.POST.get('password')
        obj=Logs()
        obj.get_special_combination_value
        for b in a:
            if name == b.name and password == b.password:
                return redirect('ticket',pk=b.id)
    return render(request,'project/loger.html',{'formy':formy,'a':a})

def plane(request):
    print(name)
    a=Logs.objects.all()
    b=Plane.objects.all()
    for c in b:
        if name==c.name:
            log_instance=Plane.objects.get(id=c.id)
            plane_instance=Plane.objects.get(id=c.id)
    for d in a:
        if name==d.name:
            plane_instance1=Logs.objects.get(id=d.id)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        checkbox_dict_json = request.POST.get('checkboxDict')
        if checkbox_dict_json:
            checkbox_dict = json.loads(checkbox_dict_json)
            log_instance.json_data = checkbox_dict
            Plane.objects.update(checkbox_dict=checkbox_dict)
    checker=plane_instance.name
    checker2=plane_instance1.name
    checkbox = log_instance.checkbox_dict
    print(checkbox)
    print(checker)
    print(checker2)
    return render(request, 'project/plane.html', {'checkbox':json.dumps(checkbox),'checker':json.dumps(checker),'checker2':json.dumps(checker2)})
```

i tried to return loger but it was only returning <HttpResponse status_code=200, "text/html; charset=utf-8">.i have no idea what to do

Comment: No need for all the noise. Give just the part of the code that isn’t working but you want to work. [See creating a minimal reproducible example.](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 0):

By looking at your code, I am assuming that functions `loger` and `plane` are two views in Django with urls pointing to it. If that is the case, it is not recommended to share a variable between the two. This can cause lot of issues, for example - If your Django deployment is with more than 1 worker, Each request could go to different worker and the context/value of the variable `name` would be different.

You will have to send the value name to the `plane` function. One way to do it is as a url parameter.

You could update your `url` for the `plane` view function as:

```py
path('plane/<str:name>/', views.plane, name='plane'),
```

and then update your `plane` function as:

```py
def plane(request, name):
    # ...
    print(name)  # You can access the name parameter here
    # ...
```